# Can a shell function behave as a command when it comes to failure status?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

For a `executable` which can fail with not zero exit codes, one can do:

```
executable && echo "suceed" || echo "failure"
```

How to do this with a shell function?

```
myfunction() {
   executable arg1 arg2
}

myfunction && echo "succeed" || echo "failure"
```

Comment: Seems like it should work as written.  Did you have a problem with the code?  If so, you need to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html):

> When executed, the exit status of a function is the exit status of the last command executed in the body.

In other words, shell functions behave exactly as you have demonstrated in your question.  For example, given:

```
myfunction() {
  false
}
```

Running:

```
myfunction && echo success || echo failed
```

Results in:

```
failed
```

On the other hand, if we have:

```
myfunction() {
  true
}
```

Running the same command returns `success`.